# R For loop - estimates and values for forecasting

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to do some regression forecasting based on my estimates and actual values. I have the following

> estimates=s1$coefficients[,1] 
> values = data.frame(cbind(sd_rgdpg,DISSIM,TRADE,SIZE,OPEN,TF,INFL,INT,NIIP))

Where estimates are my coefficients and values are my actual values. 'estimates' is a vector of ten with the intercept as the first item. 'values'is a dataframe with 9 columns and 21 rows. The columns' variables correspond to the rows of estimates. I need to multiply the variables estimates and values together to form an equation like y = intercept + b1x1+b2x2+...+b9x9.

I'm not quite sure how to do this in a forloop, can anyone help me out?

Here is the 'values' dataframe:

```
sd_rgdpg
<dbl>
DISSIM
<dbl>
TRADE
<dbl>
SIZE
<dbl>
OPEN
<dbl>
TF
<dbl>
INFL
<dbl>
INT
<dbl>
NIIP
<dbl>
0.3905156169    0.39590508  0.00000000  0.0000000000    2.629159    0.5474359   -0.40   1.43    -13.68144000
1.4482896523    0.37227806  0.03102011  0.0007919784    2.493771    0.5837563   -0.07   0.16    1.19404188
0.1698460561    0.35884028  0.10907448  0.0386795080    2.342112    0.6075000   0.22    -0.76   0.93052249
0.0020363597    0.04812418  0.24478591  0.0856910910    2.085918    0.6554404   -0.40   -1.22   0.94020757
0.3148110593    0.02315404  0.28936211  0.1649356627    2.094957    0.6589744   -3.16   -1.88   0.85515135
0.0279017603    0.02906603  0.31283051  0.2369223964    2.033051    0.6938776   -1.29   -1.36   0.57801452
0.0192319055    0.05513982  0.35421769  0.3050570794    2.137967    0.8312958   -0.02   -0.85   0.34994832
0.0358535769    0.07426063  0.48108389  0.4014364697    2.326611    0.8333333   -1.50   -0.35   -0.11022762
1.4919556927    0.05297878  0.60639908  0.4873392510    2.608321    0.8096886   -5.94   -0.76   -0.49419490
1.6980146354    0.03063955  0.75594659  0.5018749374    2.795147    0.8380282   1.27    -0.25   -0.28853577

1-10 of 21 rows | 1-5 of 9 columns
```

and here are the 'estimates'

```
 (Intercept)      sd_rgdpg         TRADE          OPEN 
-1.048798e-04 -7.023954e-06  5.159287e-06  2.467633e-04 
       DISSIM          SIZE            TF          INFL 
-5.867023e-04 -3.927840e-04 -3.241606e-04 -2.520122e-05 
          INT          NIIP 
 1.668813e-06  8.409097e-06
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Just recall that your coefficients are a vector, and your values are a matrix. Hence, your result y is also a vector. You wouldn't need a for loop. As an example:

```
intercept <- -1.05
coef <- c(-7.02, 5.16, 2.47,-5.87,-3.93,-3.23,-2.52, 1.67, 8.41)
values <- matrix(runif(27), ncol = 9) # values is a matrix with 9 columns and 3 rows of Unif[0,1] values as an example
```

Then you can just do

```
> intercept + rowSums(coef * values)
[1] -30.385560   3.734984   3.262591
```

But after training a regression model, for instance with the `lm.fit()` function, you would generally use the `predict()` function to produce results.